# New AppCompat-v7 (v21) and properties' android: prefix

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

Using the new AppCompat-v7 (v21) it seems to me that there is no more need to declare 
properties twice, once without `android:` prefix and once with the `android:` prefix, to customize the ActionBar.
Perhaps, i think, because the Action Bar Styles are already inherited from *Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat* and then overlaid without `android:` prefix in all the library's *values-vXX* xml files.
Is it just like that or am I mistaken? Thanks

**Edit:**
May be because the AppCompat-v7 (v21) always uses `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` to make the ActionBar, even when it runs on Lollipop devices?

Comment: Your edit is correct.

Comment: Then the main difference with previous versions is that the v21 is not a wrapper on the native ActionBar when this is available on the running device Android 3.0+. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

For properties which are available only on API 21 (Lollipop) you should create values-v21/ directory where you would put both 'android' and 'appcompat', e.g.

```
  <item name="colorAccent">#276181</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#276181</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#276181</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#276181</item>
```

Where in values directory (pre-21) you would put only "colorAccent" and only "colorPrimary" without android prefix (as it's not available but appcompat knows about it).

Comment: There is no need: it works on all platforms with only `colorPrimary` and the other properties without prefix in _values.xml_.

Comment: GPack, it didn't work for me when I wanted to see colors in app switcher. Setting "android:" worked for that, maybe it was fixed recently?

Comment: I am testing v21 version, I dont know it regards older versions of AppCompat-v7.

Comment: I meant that appcompat-v7 had 21.0.0 version and it was fixed with couple of bug fixed, maybe that was changed.